# Django run in docker with error "permission denied"

Tags: python, django, docker

I got an error with python environment in docker when run my django project.
The environment is:
OS: linux
Docker: 18.09.0
Docker base images: python3:latest
Command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080

error log as below:

```bash
eb-1  | Operations to perform:
web-1  |   Apply all migrations: AlarmTransServer, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
web-1  | Running migrations:
web-1  |   No migrations to apply.
web-1  | Current environment is dev
web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web-1  |   File "/app/AlarmTransServer/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
web-1  |     main()
web-1  |   File "/app/AlarmTransServer/manage.py", line 18, in main
web-1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
web-1  |     utility.execute()
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
web-1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
web-1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
web-1  |     super().execute(*args, **options)
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
web-1  |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
web-1  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 111, in handle
web-1  |     self.run(**options)
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in run
web-1  |     autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 673, in run_with_reloader
web-1  |     exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
web-1  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 274, in restart_with_reloader
web-1  |     p = subprocess.run(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
web-1  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
web-1  |     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
web-1  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
web-1  |     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1838, in _execute_child
web-1  |     self._posix_spawn(args, executable, env, restore_signals,
web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1782, in _posix_spawn
web-1  |     self.pid = os.posix_spawn(executable, args, env, **kwargs)
web-1  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web-1  | PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/local/bin/python3'
```

the code running successfully on my MAC, but when migrate to linux, it's failed. I don't have any clue, please help me, thanks a lot.

I have tried to set all files privilege to 777. it didn't work.

dockerfile and docker-compose file as below:

- dockerfile

```
FROM python

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install netcat-traditional

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
ENV APP_HOME=/app/AlarmTransServer
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

ADD . ${APP_HOME}


RUN chmod +x ./start.sh
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install cryptography


EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash ./start.sh
```

- docker-compose file

```
version: "3"

volumes: 
  db_vol: 

networks: 
  db_network:
    driver: bridge

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    env_file:  
      - ./AlarmTransServer/.env 
    networks:  
      - db_network
    volumes:
      - db_vol:/var/lib/mysql:rw 
      - ./compose/mysql/conf/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf 
      - ./compose/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ 
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" 
    restart: always

  web:
    build: ./AlarmTransServer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    # volumes:
      # - ./AlarmTransServer:/var/www/html/AlarmTransServer 
      # - ./compose/uwsgi:/tmp #
    networks:
      - db_network
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

- start.sh as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while ! nc -z db 3306 ; do
    echo "Waiting for the MySQL Server"
    sleep 3
done

python3 manage.py makemigrations&&
python3 manage.py migrate&&
APP_ENV=${APP_ENV} python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080

exec "$@"
```

Comment: So how does the docker file and compose looks like?

Comment: I also had a permission denied problem when Dockerizing the django project using Docker in ubuntu, and it was fixed with the `chmod +x scripts/start.sh` command.

Comment: I have post the dockerfile and docker-compose file below. and the start.sh has been added execute permission. seems not this reason..

Comment: Well, what does `start.sh` do?

Comment: start.sh is used for start the django app. I post the start.sh file in below answer.

Comment: I also login into the docker and try to run the 'python3 manage.py runserver' command manually, encounter same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix the issue by run container in privileged mode.
thanks for all support.

Comment: You shouldn't normally need privileged mode; it enables things like "let the container reboot the host", but it shouldn't affect whether a Python binary is runnable.